# Firebase - Retrieve User Information from Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]> I have 3 classes.

- `DriverDatabase.class`
- `AddInfoDriver.class`
- `DriverProfile.class`

In `DriverDatabase.class` I have set(fName, lName .... and other fields.). Also, put `{get; and set;}` for those attribtues.

In `AddInfoDriver.class` I have referenced `FirebaseDatabase` and `DriverDatabase.class` so that, whenever a user fills those edittexts, it saves to Firebase Database.

**The Problem is:** I cannot retrieve those 5 Edittext values in `DriverProfile.class`  below is the piece of code for retrieving.

```
public class DriverProfile extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.btn_save) Button btnsave;
@BindView(R.id.edtx_DoB) EditText edtxdob;
@BindView(R.id.edtx_fname) EditText edtx_fname;
@BindView(R.id.edtx_lname) EditText edtx_lname;
@BindView(R.id.spinner_type) Spinner spn_type;
@BindView(R.id.edtx_number) EditText edtx_number;

private DatabaseReference driverfname, driverlname;


public DriverProfile() {
//Constructed is required

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_profile, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    driverfname = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drivers").child("fname");
    driverlname  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drivers").child("lname");

    driverfname.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            edtx_fname.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Didnt write all edittext codes, just see my `ValueEventListener` for fname of Driver. it is not displaying data when saved by driver in a `child("Drivers")`

Comment: Please share your database structure.

Comment: I have edited my question, uploaded DB structure in firebase console

Comment: And you need that data for one driver or for all drivers?

Comment: For all drivers. Actually, I have SMS auth, If I understand how to retrieve it, I will do then after every authentication. Every Driver personal information should be displayed in his own page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values from all drivers please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference driversRef = rootRef.child("Drivers");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String cardNumber = ds.child("cardNumber").getValue(String.class);
            String cardType = ds.child("cardType").getValue(String.class);
            String dateOfBirth = ds.child("dateOfBirth").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String surname = ds.child("surname").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", cardNumber + " / " + cardType + " / " + dateOfBirth + " / " + name + " / " + surname);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
driversRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Perfect solution bro!! thank you. Can I ask one more thing @Alex?

Comment: in one project, I have to apps. How to connect two apps together to share data. Client app and Driver app. client orders hotdog and other snacks, driver should see those orders. I have done all tasks with recyclerview and adapters. the only thing left is to connect two apps together. read documentations, not clear for me really

Comment: I think that you may be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874920/can-multiple-android-application-access-same-firebase-database).

Comment: great. thanx bro

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155582/discussion-between-zoffa-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Just answered your last question.