# Firebase - Edit/Update Database on Button Click after Retrieving

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am Retrieving values from Firebase Database in 4 `Edittexts` and 1 `Spinner`.

- Edittext -> fName
- Edittext -> lName
- Edittext -> dateOfBirth
- Spinner ->  carType
- Edittext -> carNumber

All these values are displayed. But how to edit them and update under button clicked.?

> Followed [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), but no success.

Please look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484046/firebase-retrieve-user-information-from-database). you will understand

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: It is unclear of what you are trying to do.Do you want to update the data in the database? Also, post the code as how are you updating the data.

Comment: Are you using `setValue()` to update the values?

Comment: Yes I am using setValue()

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the same database structure as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484046/firebase-retrieve-user-information-from-database/46484187) please use the following code:

```
final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        rootRef.child("Drivers").child(driverId).child("carNumber").setValue("newCarNumber");
    }
});
```

In which `driverId` is the id of the particular driver for which you want to make updates.
For the other fields just change `carNumber` with `cardType`, `dateOfBirth`, `name` or `surname`.

If you want to update data for the last driver for example, use this line:

```
rootRef.child("Drivers").child("-Kv6q2beyS50VCxxX3M7").child("carNumber").setValue("newCarNumber");
```

Comment: Hello, i am also using this method but i am having an issue. The data uploads to firebase but when the same data is deleted the onclick method runs it self and upload what ever is present in the edit texts. Note: this happens when app is open in background or foreground.

Comment: @MohammadMaaz Without seeing the code that you are using, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I did a work around and now I am not having the problem. Before i was using 'valueEventListener' which was causing the button click to run itself when the data was changed. After some learning i found that 'addListenerForSingleValueEvent' will run 1 time only, and this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy, i am not shure if i understand what you need.

```
public void editData(String childKey, String fName, String lName, String dateOfBirth, String carType, String carNumber) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(childKey);
    databaseReference.child("fName").setValue(fName);
    databaseReference.child("lName").setValue(lName);
    databaseReference.child("dateOfBirth").setValue(dateOfBirth);
    databaseReference.child("carType").setValue(carType);
    databaseReference.child("carNumber").setValue(carNumber);
}
```