# Firebase Database- Display users

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, rules

To display list of users in my app from Firebase Database,what rule do i need to publish?
have tried this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484046/firebase-retrieve-user-information-from-database),yet did'nt find my answers

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to users registered using firebase sign up ( with email, Google account, etc). You will not be able to retrieve that sensitive information in client side. You will have to create a  backend server using firebase api and there you retrieve the users information. You will have to implement a proper authorization in your backend.