# How to transfer data between two different apps, each one of them is installed on different device?

Tags: android

From the title you can till what exactly I am seeking for.
I developed two different apps .. The first one is going to be used by a doctor, while the second one is going to be used by a patient.

One of the extra services that is provided to the patient is a simple "consultation requst" from a doctor.
Here is the doctor role begains ..

The two apps are totally distinct !!Each one of them on different a device .. How I can transfer the consultation request (text and image) from patient to doctor .. And send a replay on that from the doctor side ?!!

Thanks a lot ..

Comment: Paitient --> Server --> Doctor and vice versa .

Comment: That's it ! Oh thanks a lot Rehan

Comment: Use the Firebase realtime database for storing the data and use the firebase storage for image loading.And for two different app access the same firebase database you can take the reference from this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874920/can-multiple-android-application-access-same-firebase-database

Answer (score 0):

Malak You can use the Firebase realtime database for storing the data and for storing the image you can use the Firebase cloud storage.Because you develop two different package app so you must need to this [Can multiple android application access same firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874920/can-multiple-android-application-access-same-firebase-database)
Another option is to make your own **REST API** using the Nodejs, PHP, Java or any other server side programming language and use the MySQL or MongoDB for database and deploy this rest api in SAP heoku or Microsoft azure.But this second option will be harder for the beginner.So i would suggest you should try to use First option(Firebase database).

Comment: Thanks a lot Rishabh for the detailed answer ! I am gonna try my shot with Firebase.